# Using user-inputted characters in If/Switch statements

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

I am taking my first Java class, and am having a hard time finishing this assignment.

The assignment itself is quite simple. All I have to do is prompt the user to input an integer, a character, then another integer.

If the character inputted is +, the two integers should be added together. If the character inputted is -, the two integers should be subtracted. Etc...

**The problem is that I do not know how to accept a character from the user, then use it in my If/Switch statements.**

Here are my prompts:

```
// Prompt the user to enter an integer
    System.out.print("Please enter an integer number:");
    int int1  = input.nextInt();

// Prompt the user to enter a character
// Since I could not use characters, I am using integers to represent them.
    System.out.print("Enter 0 for +, 1 for -, 2 for /, 3 for %, and 4 for *");
    int char1 = input.nextInt();

// Prompt the user to enter another integer
    System.out.print("Please enter another integer number:");
    int int2 = input.nextInt();
```

Here are my If/Switch statements: (I know they are redundant, but it's part of the assignment)

```
if (char1 == 0) {
    int ans = int1 + int2;
    System.out.println(int1 + " + " + int2 + " = " + ans);
} else if (char1 == 1) {
    int ans = int1 - int2;
    System.out.println(int1 + " - " + int2 + " = " + ans);
} else if (char1 == 2) {
    int ans = int1 / int2;
    System.out.println(int1 + " / " + int2 + " = " + ans);
} else if (char1 == 3) {
    int ans = int1 % int2;
    System.out.println(int1 + " % " + int2 + " = " + ans);
} else if (char1 == 4) {
    int ans = int1 * int2;
    System.out.println(int1 + " * " + int2 + " = " + ans);
} else
    System.out.println("Invalid operator");

int result = 0;
switch (char1) {
    case 0: result = int1 + int2;
            System.out.println(int1 + " + " + int2 + " = " + result); break;
    case 1: result = int1 - int2;
            System.out.println(int1 + " - " + int2 + " = " + result); break;
    case 2: result = int1 / int2;
            System.out.println(int1 + " / " + int2 + " = " + result); break;
    case 3: result = int1 % int2;
            System.out.println(int1 + " % " + int2 + " = " + result); break;
    case 4: result = int1 * int2;
            System.out.println(int1 + " * " + int2 + " = " + result); break;
    default: System.out.println("Invalid operator");
}
```

Everything else works just fine. I'm just trying to change from using 0 for +, 1 for -, to just using +, -, /, %, and *.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can take the operator from the user as **String** or **Char**

Like this :

```
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Prompt the user to enter an integer
        System.out.print("Please enter an integer number:");
        int int1 = input.nextInt();

// Prompt the user to enter a character
// Since I could not use characters, I am using integers to represent them.
        System.out.print("Enter +, -,  /,  %, *");
        char char1 = input.next().charAt(0);

// Prompt the user to enter another integer
        System.out.print("Please enter another integer number:");
        int int2 = input.nextInt();

        if (char1=='+') {
            int ans = int1 + int2;
            System.out.println(int1 + " + " + int2 + " = " + ans);
        } else if (char1=='-') {
            int ans = int1 - int2;
            System.out.println(int1 + " - " + int2 + " = " + ans);
        } else if (char1=='/') {
            int ans = int1 / int2;
            System.out.println(int1 + " / " + int2 + " = " + ans);
        } else if (char1=='%') {
            int ans = int1 % int2;
            System.out.println(int1 + " % " + int2 + " = " + ans);
        } else if (char1=='*') {
            int ans = int1 * int2;
            System.out.println(int1 + " * " + int2 + " = " + ans);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid operator");
        }

        int result = 0;

        switch (char1) {
            case '+':
                result = int1 + int2;
                System.out.println(int1 + " + " + int2 + " = " + result);
                break;
            case '-':
                result = int1 - int2;
                System.out.println(int1 + " - " + int2 + " = " + result);
                break;
            case '/':
                result = int1 / int2;
                System.out.println(int1 + " / " + int2 + " = " + result);
                break;
            case '%':
                result = int1 % int2;
                System.out.println(int1 + " % " + int2 + " = " + result);
                break;
            case '*':
                result = int1 * int2;
                System.out.println(int1 + " * " + int2 + " = " + result);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid operator");
        }
```

Comment: You're awesome! I was trying to do char char1 = input.charAt(0)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
System.out.print("Enter +, -, /, or *");
char char1 = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
```

`nextLine` will get the entire thing that the user input, and `charAt` gets the character at the specified index.

Therefore, `charAt(0)` gets the first character. Here is a visual explanation: the top is the string and the bottom is what character number it is:

```
|t|h|i|s| |i|s| |a| |t|e|s|t|
-----------------------------
|0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|1|1|1|1|
| | | | | | | | | | |0|1|2|3|
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! What's the difference between next() and nextLine()?

Comment: @user2037733: `next()` reads an `int` and `nextLine()` reasd a hole line (as a `String`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `char` from the user input this way:

A `char` is only an unsigned integer value 0..65535 so you can write e.g. `+` for the value `43` [Which is the unicode of '+']

```
switch (char1) {
    case '+': result = int1 + int2;
        System.out.println(int1 + " + " + int2 + " = " + result); break;
    case '-': result = int1 - int2;
        System.out.println(int1 + " - " + int2 + " = " + result); break;
    case '/': result = int1 / int2;
        System.out.println(int1 + " / " + int2 + " = " + result); break;
    case '%': result = int1 % int2;
        System.out.println(int1 + " % " + int2 + " = " + result); break;
    case '*': result = int1 * int2;
        System.out.println(int1 + " * " + int2 + " = " + result); break;
    default: System.out.println("Invalid operator");
}
```

Comment: You expect the user to enter "43" if he wants to add something? -1

Comment: @Doorknob: I expect the user to enter the character '+' which is the same as value (ASCII 43 which allows us to use it in the switch even in java < 7)

Comment: @Doorknob: Of cause you do not read it with `.nextInt()`. I assume such little thinking can be left for the reader. The variable name `char1` already implies that **user2037733** intended to read a `char`.

Comment: @Doorknob: And the other pert is: how to *'use it in my If/Switch statements'* which is what I explained in my answer.

Comment: `Everything else works just fine. I'm just trying to change from using 0 for +, 1 for -, to just using +, -, /, %, and *.` (direct quote)

Comment: Mine was also a quotation *The problem is that I do not know how to accept a character from the user, then use it in my If/Switch statements.* (direct quote)

Comment: but you don't explain that in your answer.

Comment: I explan how to use `char` in a `switch`-stateent and why you can do it this way even in java < 7. By the way as you can see in the answer of *Alya'a Gamal* I am not the only one who thinks that the usage of the input is part of the question.

Comment: I am fine when you do not like my answer, because it is not for you but for *user2037733*. I can live with your -1.